# NLS_LANG AL32UTF8/UTF8 for Oracle database

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, ubuntu, environment-variables, sysdba

I recently installed a new Oracle database on Ubuntu using this [tutorial](http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2014/03/18/installing-java-oracle-11g-r2-express-edition-and-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-64-bit/).

I got an error

```
oracle@ubuntu:/home/bruno$ echo $NLS_LANG
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/nls_lang.sh
oracle@ubuntu:/home/bruno$ /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/nls_lang.sh
AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
oracle@ubuntu:/home/bruno$ sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Thu Mar 17 11:00:45 2016
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
ERROR:
ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified
Enter user-name:
```

After searching, I found a possible solution:

```
oracle@ubuntu:/home/bruno$ export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
oracle@ubuntu:/home/bruno$ sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Thu Mar 17 11:03:15 2016
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
SQL>
```

What is the most elegant way to correct this error?

---

Answer

`export NLS_LANG = $($ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh)`

Comment: but did you run `. oraenv` before doing that?

Comment: No, I did `source  /etc/bash.bashrc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original tutorial:

```
export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
```

Notice the backticks. The value of `NLS_LANG` variable should be the output of the above command, not the file name with absolute path. Just set the value of NLS_LANG, as you already did:

`export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`

Comment: Thank you, with your answer got the following response
 export NLS_LANG=$($ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh)